# UserManual.chm file Does not showing Contents?

Tags: chm

[image: UserManual.chm]

my UserManual.chm file file does not displaying content.
i dont know why it's not working on my Computer.

please help me to find out solution

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft is trying to protect you from CHM files.

If a CHM file is downloaded from a server (UNC-Path) you can't view the Content without . Copy the CHM file to a local drive and try again. You may try another CHM file on a local drive.

If a CHM file is unzipped from a ZIP download please open Windows Explorer, find your CHM file, right-click and select properties and click the Unblock button on the General tab.